# Apipie with docs separate from controller code

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using the [Apipie gem](https://github.com/Apipie/apipie-rails), which I find great in every way except it seems that I have to include my API documentation right inside my controller code, which IMO really hurts the easy navigability of the code. Is there any way to use Apiepie but have the documentation separate somewhow?

Comment: Good question - I looked at Apipie but I found it really offputting that you have a bunch of executable documentation code which runs in production.